# JQuery Timing with the load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to make a tool for my work and the timing is messing me up a lot. Hopefully someone can help here. Below is my code that I currently have. The issue is when I grab a selected item and run the `$("#JJ_HOLDER").load()`, it is sometimes not waiting to finish. I need everything to finish in the callback function THEN run the `submitTaskbyHolder()` but only when it is complete. Any and all help is appreciated!

End Goal: Run `RunCad()` and have it load data into `$("#JJ_HOLDER")` then run `submitTaskbyHolder()` then empty and repeat with another data set (`parseInt(selected[i])`)

```
function submitTaskbyHolder(){
  var loginUser = $("#hdnUserID").data('value');
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: app.global.AppPath + 'WorkRequestDetails/SubmitWorkRequestDetails/',
      data: $('#FormID').serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (result) {
          if (result.Status == "Show Add Module") {
              app.workRequestDetails.OpenWorkRequestDetailsPopup("Submit");
          }
          else {
              if (result.Status == "Module submitted.") {
                  if (result.ModuleAndStatus.CurrentAssignedId == loginUser) {
                      app.modalPopup.isCancel = false;
                      $("#BTNStop").click();
                      app.workRequestDetails.display_notifyresultA("Successfully submitted work request.");
                      $('#HFCurrentModuleID').val(result.ModuleAndStatus.ModuleId);
                      $('#HFCurrentStatusID').val(result.ModuleAndStatus.StatusId);
                      $('#txtModule').val(result.ModuleAndStatus.ModuleName);
                      $('#txtStatus').val(result.ModuleAndStatus.StatusName);
                      console.log('submitted');
                  }
                  else {
                      app.modalPopup.isCancel = false;
                      app.layoutdash.display_notifyresult("Successfully submitted work request.");
                      console.log('submitted');
                  }
              }
              else {
                  swal(result.Status);
              }
          }
      },
      error: function (result) {
          swal(result.Status);
      }
  });
}

var i = 0;
function RunCad() {
  selected = app.dashboardGridview.selectedItems;
  if(selected.length == 0){
    swal({title: "Error", 
          text: "Ensure there is more than one selected!", 
          icon: "error", 
          button: "Okay",
    });
  }else{
   setTimeout(function () {
      $("#JJ_HOLDER").empty();
      $("#JJ_HOLDER").load(app.global.AppPath + 'WorkRequestDetails/GetWorkRequestDetails/', { projectID: parseInt(selected[i]) },function() {
          $(body).css('padding-right', '0px');
          app.addWorkRequest.LoadTooltipsterToPopup();
          app.multiSelectSettings.MultiSelectSettings();
          app.modalPopup.Loadfunctions('WorkRequestDetails/GetWorkRequestDetails/');
          app.modalPopup.FixTabPressModalPopup();
          submitTaskbyHolder();
          console.log(selected[i] + ' is complete!');
      });
      i++;
      if (i+1 < app.dashboardGridview.selectedItems.length) {
         RunCad();
      }else{
        app.modalPopup.ReloadDashboardView();
      }
   }, 3000)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to use promise

Comment: @MisterJojo Promise is very confusing to me so hopefully there is another route xD